# Estoy aprendiendo JS de un libro y el navegador me da el siguiente error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: html, java-swing

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de un libro, sobre un reloj, este es el código JS del libro:

```
var mie =(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")>=0) 
function actReloj() 
{ 
var hhmmss=new Date() 
var horas=hhmmss.getHours() 
var minutos=hhmmss.getMinutes() 
var segundos=hhmmss.getSeconds() 

horas = (horas<=9)?("0"+horas):horas; 
minutos = (minutos<=9)?("0"+minutos):minutos; 
segundos=(segundos<=9)? ("0"+segundos):segundos; 

reloj="<font size='5' face='Arial' ><b>"+horas+":"+minutos+":" 
+segundos +"</b></font>" `<-- Creo que el error se genera aca`
if (mie) 
 { 
 reloj.innerHTML=reloj; 
 } 
else 
 { 
 document.layers.reloj.document.write(reloj); 
 document.layers.reloj.document.close(); 
 } 
//ejecuta la función cada segundo (1000 miliseg) 
setTimeout("actReloj()",1000); 
}
```

En el HTML se debería leer en un DIV como el siguiente:

```
<div id="reloj">
    
</div>
```

He buscado soluciones varias en internet pero no creo hallar la solución a mi problema. De antemano te agradezco por tomar de tu tiempo para ayudarme

Comment: Java Swing es una biblioteca visual de Java. ¡Lo tuyo es Javascript! Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta, y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Ese libro está totalmente obsoleto

- [navigator.appName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appName)  (obsoleto)
- [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)  (obsoleto)
- document.layers: Esto creo que es de las primeras versiones de javascript, no lo pude encontrar en la documentación actual
- setTimeout: Debe recibir una función en su primer argumento, no recuerdo si alguna vez se pudo pasar un string. Además está funcion no te sirve para un reloj, en su lugar debes usar setInterval

Javascript es un lenguaje que nació con una series de fallos enormes, por lo que ha tenido constantes mejoras, y cada vez estas mejoras están llegando más rápido, por lo que es importante estar actualizados

Tu código queda así:

```js
const reloj = document.getElementById("reloj");
function actReloj() 
{ 
  let hhmmss=new Date() 
  let horas=hhmmss.getHours() 
  let minutos=hhmmss.getMinutes() 
  let segundos=hhmmss.getSeconds() 

  horas = String(horas).padStart(2,"0"); //padleft agrega ceros a la izquierda 
  minutos = String(horas).padStart(2,"0");
  segundos=String(segundos).padStart(2,"0");

  reloj.innerHTML=`${horas}:${minutos}:${segundos}`;
} 
 
//ejecuta la función cada segundo (1000 miliseg) 

// setTimeout ejecuta UNA vez luego de 1000 ms
//setTimeout(actReloj,1000); 

//tu necesitas setInterval
setInterval(actReloj,1000);
```

```css
#reloj{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div id="reloj"></div>
```